# Display the current date, day of the week, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: sql

I am working with SQL Oracle.
So, how can I write a syntax to display the current date, day of the week, hours, minutes, and seconds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there `SYSDATE()` is your solution

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW" FROM DUMMY;
```

Output

```
NOW
-------------------
02-27-2021 20:50:04
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I display also "Saturday 02-27-2021 20:50:04"?

Comment: select to_char(date'2018-01-01', 'DAY') full_name

Check this page:  https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GCEY1DN2CN5HZCUQFHVUYQD3G.html